# How can I run 2 already installed OS at the same time?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualization, multi-boot

I have Win7 and Ubuntu installed on my PC, and I can choose which to run at boot time. I would like to be able to run the Ubuntu from within the Win7. Tools like VMWare allows one to create a new installation of a guest OS, which could then be run alongside the hosting OS. However, I already have the Ubuntu fully installed on my hard drive, and I'd like to maintain the dual boot option.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to create a new virtual machine on my Win7, but instead of installing a new guest OS, just direct it to the existing installation. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

This shows how to boot Windows in Linux, I believe reverse should be possible:
https://serverfault.com/questions/76301/start-windows-in-virtual-machine-from-real-hard-drive-partion

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe this is what you are looking for - http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=3118462&postcount=5

Answer (score -3):

[Check this out, WUBI installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/windows-installer)

Comment: WUBI lets you install Ubuntu from within Windows, but it won't let you run Ubuntu from within Windows, would it? I already have Ubuntu installed, and I'd like to be able to use the existing installation.